# Which database fits for 14 million records with PHP as frontend

Tags: php, mysql, mongodb, database, nosql

I have to work on the business search portal in which, i think the proposed records to be entered and searched would be around 14 million.

I am planing to use PHP as frontend and Mysql as backend. But i think it will reduce the overall performance of the site. So kindly suggest which backend to go with?

Best Regards

Comment: MySQL.. 14M records is not that BIG

Comment: First, just because this annoys me with job postings, PHP _is_ a backend, being a server-side language.  The combo of HTML/CSS/Javascript/etc is the front-end.

Comment: MySQL is more than capable of handling this many records, because it's not really as big as you think: there's companies out there using MySQL for that many new records each day - what makes you think it will reduce the overall performance of the site?

Comment: @Jon I guess he meant frontend as the interface or language driver through which he would be connecting and making db calls. A overloaded term really. I agree with your point though :P

Comment: @SushantGupta Yeah. Haha, I see postings "Looking for a front end PHP developer that knows HTML." Let's you know who you definitely don't want to pick up freelance work from. lol ^^

Answer (score 1):

It's depending on your DBSchema and the way you use data.
Mysql and the fork MariaDB are great for this job :)

Answer (score 1):

One thing that stood out to me was the word: "searched". It is listed as one of the core functions you require.

The problem with both SQL and NoSQL databases is that, if I am honest, they still kind of suck at searching.

MongoDB has got an extremely alpha FTS feature, however, as I just mentioned it is extremely alpha and has no real hooks to the client drivers currently. Not only that but it is likely to change its API in its current state.

Considering you want one of the core purposes of the site to be searching I would recommend you either have a dedicated FTS tech or you have both a SQL/NoSQL database with a FTS tech on top.

I personally prefer Sphinx search, however, I have used Solr with considerable success.

There are, of course, other FTS techs out there like Lucene, Elastic Search, etc.

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL: The ultimate option.Lightweight and optimized.Still,what @KLK1 suggest. It's depending on your DBSchema and the way you use data.

Answer (score 0):

The performance of the database depends more on the way you organize your data (this means, your database-schema), then on the database itself. You can have the fastest db money can buy, if you have a bad database-schema in it, performance could be far worse then a well designed database-schema on a normal database.
As said in the comments, 14 million records isn't that much at all, MySQL can cope with this, as can MongoDB.